# Append contents of one file into another

Tags: bash

```
> for filename in '*.sql'
> do
> echo "@some_string" >> $filename
> done
-bash: $filename: ambiguous redirect
```

when i try to append a constant to all files i get a error ambigous redirect.

Any idea how to solve this issue ?

Comment: And those quotes around `*.sql` seem a bit strange.

Comment: Changing cat to echo i get the same results

Comment: Hi Mat spot on i removed the quotes around *.sql and it worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
for filename in *.sql
do
echo "@some_string" >> "$filename"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use

```
#!/bin/bash
for filename in *.sql
do
echo "@some_string" >> "$filename"
done
```

The problem with your code is in

```
cat "@some_string"
```

since `cat` expects a filename.

As stated by @c00kiemon5ter, you should also quote `$filename`, since it could contain spaces.

Comment: also the quotes around `*.sql` were wrong. and you also need quotes around `$filename`