# Catenate files with blank lines between them

Tags: bash, for-loop

How can we copy all the contents of all the files in a given directory into a file **so that there are two empty lines between contents of each files**?

Need not to mention, I am new to bash scripting, and I know this is not an extra complicated code!

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Related links are following:
 * [How do I compare the contents of all the files in a directory against another directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28555826/how-do-i-compare-the-contents-of-all-the-files-in-a-directory-against-another-di)
 * [Append contents of one file into another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382330/append-contents-of-one-file-into-another)
 * [BASH: Copy all files and directories into another directory in the same parent directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20832544/bash-copy-all-files-and-directories-into-another-directory-in-the-same-parent-d)

After reading comments, my initial attempt is this:

```
cat * > newfile.txt
```

**But this does not create two empty lines between contents of each new files.**

Comment: `cat` is your friend, read the man page.

Comment: `cat * > newfile.txt`..

Comment: Can you explain why you rolled back my title edit? You will continue to receive `cat *` answers with the current title.

Comment: @tripleee I tried to correct extra blank spaces, it is more than welcome if you edit the question again!

Comment: @tripleee is it better to delete duplicate question, or what can i do?

Comment: Duplicates are fine as long as they are not completely identical; a question with slightly different wording may help future visitors find the result and ultimately the question and the answers that this one is now marked as duplicating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
awk 'FNR==1 && NR>1 { printf("\n\n") }1' * >newfile.txt
```

The variable `FNR` is the line number within the current file and `NR` is the line number overall.

Answer (score 1):

One way:

```
(
    files=(*)
    cat "${files[0]}"
    for (( i = 1; i < "${#files[@]}" ; ++i )) ; do
        echo
        echo
        cat "${files[i]}"
    done
) > newfile.txt
```

Comment: this did not worked for me, the newfile.txt has only the contents of the first file.

Comment: There's a typo, the middle part of the `for` line should be `i < "${#files[@]}"`-- note the `#` to obtain the number of elements of the array.

Comment: @tripleee now it worked!

Comment: @tripleee: Oops, fixed now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

### Example of file organization:

I have a directory ~/Pictures/Temp

If I wanted to move PNG's from that directory to another directory I would first want to set a variable for my file names:

```
# This could be other file types as well
file=$(find ~/Pictures/Temp/*.png)
```

Of course there are many ways to view this check out:

```
$ man find
$ man ls
```

Then I would want to set a directory variable (especially if this directory is going to be something like a date

```
dir=$(some defining command here perhaps an awk of an ls -lt)
# Then we want to check for that directories existence and make it if
# it doesn't exist
[[ -e $dir ]] || mkdir "$dir"
# [[ -d $dir ]] will work here as well
```

You could write a for loop:

```
# t is time with the sleep this will be in seconds
# super useful with an every minute crontab
for ((t=1; t<59; t++));
do
    # see above
    file=$(blah blah)
    # do nothing if there is no file to move
    [[ -z $file ]] || mv "$file" "$dir/$file"
    sleep 1
done
```

Please Google this if any of it seems unclear here are some useful links:
https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/For-Statement.html
http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html

### Best link on this page is below:

http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031

### Edit:

Anyhow where I was going with that whole answer is that you could easily write a script that will organize certain files on your system for 60 sec and write a crontab to automatically do your organizing for you:

```
crontab -e
```

Here is an example

```
$ crontab -l
* * * * * ~/Applications/Startup/Desktop-Cleanup.sh
# where ~/Applications/Startup/Desktop-Cleanup.sh is a custom application that I wrote
```

Comment: Uh, this seems tangential at best.

Comment: I have ADHD... my bad

Comment: Perhaps you'll want to create a new question where this would actually be topical as an answer. I'm afraid it's likely to be deleted from here.

Comment: How so? Bhishan Poudel was talking about file organization with a bash scripting. I gave him an example of how this could be done without scripting this out for him.

Comment: @tripleee I see what you are saying in all fairness I misread the first iteration of the question. You should look at rev 1. It seems like an entirely different question.